# Find two same digits between two numbers Python

Tags: python

Code didnt pass only last check (5000,50000)

Program have to find at least 2 same digit in range of numbers.
For example:

- max_multiple(20,33) ==> 1 (number 22)
- max_multiple(0,101) ==> 10

```py
import traceback


def two_identical(start, finish):
    count = 0
    check = 0
    while (start+1)<finish:     
        start = start + 1       
        govno = start           
        while govno>0:          
            b = govno % 10     
            c = govno // 10    
            while c>0:             
                check = c % 10    
                if check == b:     
                    count = count + 1     
                    govno = 0              
                    break                   
                c=c//10      
            govno=govno//10
    return (count)
    


# tests
try:
    assert two_identical(20, 33) == 1
    assert two_identical(0, 10) == 0
    assert two_identical(0, 101) == 10
    assert two_identical(0, 1000) == 261
    assert two_identical(5000, 50000) == 35198
except AssertionError:
    print("TEST ERROR")
    traceback.print_exc()
else:
    print("TEST PASSED")
```

Comment: Not clear. You want the number of numbers in the range that have 2 times the same digit? Exactly two, or at least two, and do those have to be exactly next to each other?

Comment: Maybe a number like `11223` should be counted twice as it has two pairs? With that method I get 35,199 for the last testcase.

Comment: @tobias_k i meant, when you get range of numbers, for example, from 1345 to 1350, your programm counts numbers that have at least to same digits, like 1355, thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with by casting the int in list of strings representing each digits and add the number of duplicate elements:

```
def two_identical(start, finish):
    counter=0
    for i in range(start+1,finish,1):
        #Convert the digit in list of str. e.g 100 => ['1','0','0']
        i=[digit for digit in str(i)]
        #add the len of set of duplicate =>
        #e.g.: ['4', '9', '9', '7', '7'] => {'9','7'} => counter +=2
        #e.g.: ['4', '9', '9', '9', '7'] => {'9'} => counter +=1
        #e.g.:['4', '9', '9', '9', '4'] => {'9','4'} => counter +=2
        counter+=len(set([x for x in i if i.count(x) >1]))

    print(f"counter ({start},{finish}):{counter}")
    return counter

try:
    assert two_identical(20, 33) == 1
    assert two_identical(0, 10) == 0
    assert two_identical(0, 101) == 10
    assert two_identical(0, 1000) == 261
    assert two_identical(5000, 50000) == 35198
except AssertionError:
    print("TEST ERROR")
    #traceback.print_exc()
else:
    print("TEST PASSED")
```

result:

```
counter (20,33):1
counter (0,10):0
counter (0,101):10
counter (0,1000):261
counter (5000,50000):35198
TEST PASSED
```

Comment: The output "TEST ERROR" does not look very convincing. Seems like you have to start with `start+1` (i.e. a strictly exclusive range)

Comment: I know... but it looks like the last assert test is wrong... because there is no reason than it didn't failed between (0 and 1000) and failed between (5000 and 50000)...

Comment: Or maybe your right by starting on start+1... :) thx

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a misunderstanding in what to do. It seems like you have to count numbers like `11233` that have two duplicate numbers twice, of which there are quite a few for the last test case.

I am not sure how exactly your algorithm works, but the following works.

```
def two_identical(start, finish):
    return sum(1 for s in map(str, range(start+1, finish))
                 for c in set(s) if s.count(c) > 1)
```